# Deleting all documents in CouchDB

Tags: python-3.x, couchdb, couchdb-python, couchdb-2.0

I have a database and I want to truncate all records, I know it is possible to just add a _deleted key to every document or call db.delete() on CouchDB-python library. I am using the `delete` of couchdb-python but it does not seem to work when I fetch all the documents and then call .delete on each document excluding design documents.

Here is my code.

```
docs = get_db().view('_all_docs', include_docs=True)
for i in docs:
    if not(i['id'].startswith('_')):
        get_db().delete(i)
```

This is the error. Because the result from `_all_docs` is returning a `id` instead `_id`.

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\couchdb\client.py", line 625, in delete
if doc['_id'] is None:
KeyError: '_id'
```

My question is how do I fetch all documents that returns `_id` instead of just the `id`? Or is there any way around this?

Comment: Why do you want this? Wouldn't it be easier just to delete and re-create the database?

Comment: If I drop the database, then I'd have to recreate all my views again? Is that right? Sorry, I am fairly new with Couch. @Flimzy

Comment: Yes. But hopefully you have an easy way to do that.

Comment: Do you need to use i['id'] with delete?

Comment: that is the problem, I need `_id'` for the delete but Couch is returning `'id'` instead. @Istvan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `couchdb-python` a `view` query returns a list of `couchdb.client.Row` objects, not a list of the docs. You need to pass an attribute `doc` to that `delete`, i.e. `get_db().delete(i['doc'])`.

From performance perspective, however, it's better to use [bulk api](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.0/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-bulk-docs). With `couchdb-python` it should look something like this:

```
rows = get_db().view('_all_docs', include_docs=True)
docs = []
for row in rows:
    if row['id'].startswith('_'):
        continue
    doc = row['doc']
    doc['_deleted'] = True
    docs.append(doc)
get_db().update(docs)
```

Comment: great. I thought adding _deleted would work. Thank you. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting documents from CouchDB you can create in two step:

- create a view (with filtering the documents you want to delete)
- use the view to delete all documents using the view

I have written a [tool](https://github.com/l1x/hasta-la-vista) for this.

Comment: seems a little complicated and I want it to be python-centric.

Comment: I do the same and quite often has exception with Resource conflict. I'm thinking now how avoid this this issue.